# Which separator should be used in the Content-Type header for a multipart data request? Comma or Semicolon?

Tags: rest, content-type

Should the `Content-Type` header in a REST API web request be formatted with a comma as in [RFC 1867](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt):

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
```

Or with a semicolon, as in [RFC 1049](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1049) and [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1):

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08j34c0p
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's really all just a simple mistake and the `;` is correct.

RFC 1867 was an experimental definition.  All subsequent definitions have corrected this mistake.  For example:

- [RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) explicitly replaces 1867 and refers to [HTML 40](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) for the (correct) definition of the separator.
- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) explicitly refers to 2388 as the definition to use in HTTP/1.1.

And finally...  there is also an [official correction](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=1867) to RFC 1867 to make it use the correct delimiter.

Comment: So to summarise, the `;` is correct? (I'm surprised you wrote all that and missed this fact out)

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa Yes - now clarified.  The detail was requested by the OP to prove which interpretation was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Rely on the newest [RFC: 7231, section 3.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1) says:

```
media-type = type "/" subtype *( OWS ";" OWS parameter )
```

This leaves no room for interpretations or custom formats.

Comment: Does it say somewhere that this supersedes the RFCs in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not the first case I see, when several RFCs conflicts one with another.

In this exact case, RFC 1049 is explicitly cover `Content-type` header.  RFC 2045 is referencing to RFC 1049. Moreover, RFC 2045 dated November 1996, so it's latest one.

Opposite case is covered in RFC 1867 very briefly.

So, I suggest to use semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your two conflicting examples aren't really contradictory. 
The first, RFC-1867, defines extensions to HTML. The other two, RFC-1049 and RFC-2045, both define extensions to the Internet Mail protocol.

For a REST API, I would probably go with RFC-1867, which was designed with HTML over HTTP in mind, as opposed to the other two, which were designed with RFC-822-based emails over SMTP/POP/IMAP in mind.